# FATAL ERROR: v8::Object::SetInternalField() Internal field out of bounds on Node js using node-cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes, node-modules

I have a api export with a lot of data so I tried to used the node-cache so the api will be faster since take more than 2 min to get the data, I am new on this so I found the follow code:
Notes: env node js/express

```
const NodeCache = require("node-cache");
const axios = require('axios');
const myCache = new NodeCache({stdTTL:100000})
 axios.get('http://localhost:5000/test/example)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            myCache.set("exampleCache",response,10000);
            res.send(response)
```

Any suggestion or recommend will be great!

Comment: Also stuck on this but don't know where is the exception coming from.

Comment: Try to find NodeCache use the clone for setting response. If yes then you can not clone the request and response. We also have issues with cloning requests and responses.

Comment: Yes, I used the cache with a timeout so can refresh the data but we had to increase the memory from the db not the best solution but that was the client request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was using a buffer but since we had to many data, the increase the memory from the db was the solution

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, what I did was to **stringify** the content before saving it and **parse** it after retrieval. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [NodeCache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) module clones the object before saving it.

In your case, you're trying to cache the [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) response object, which cannot be cloned by [NodeCache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) (it's a big and complex object), so you're getting the error.

Instead, I recommend cloning the HTTP response data (response.data), which is much smaller and clonable. Or, you can clone the whole Axios response object, like in your code example, but you need to set the option `{useClones: false}` during initialization of NodeCache, this way the NodeCache will save just the reference to the object.